# How to display an Image object (from the Image package) in my Flutter app

Tags: flutter, image, dart, crop

I want to repeatedly crop different parts of an image (that I have loaded from my app's assets) and display this cropped part. I am using the copyCrop method from the image package to get a portion of the original image. The copyCrop method gives me an Image object (defined in the image package) but I can't find a way to use it in an Image widget.

What I have at the moment is:

I include the package:

```
import 'package:image/image.dart' as img;
```

Then, in an initialise routine, I load the asset into a class level variable (which is an img.Image type):

```
imageBytes = img.decodeImage(File('assets/main.jpg').readAsBytesSync())!;
```

Then I call the following whenever I need a certain part of the original image:

```
Uint8List getACrop(int x, int y)
{
  var cropppedImage = img.copyCrop(
      imageBytes,
      x: x,
      y: y,
      width: 400,
      height: 400,
    );
  return cropppedImage.getBytes();
}
```

Then, in my widget, I have:

```
Image.memory(_imgCropper.getACrop(startX, startY)),
```

But I get a 'Invalid image data' exception at the Image.memory instruction.

How can I convert the image package Image object into something I can use in an Image() widget ?

Or is there a better way of loading an image once and then being able to repeatedly extract part of that image and display it on screen ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you find the way?